# my shell script inside shell script not getting int variable

Tags: linux, shell

Im getting int value a and b using scrip1.sh and then trying to pass those values to another script (say script2.sh) which is inside script1.sh and where script2.sh which has a url and which is expecting this variables a n b eg. http://download-$a-$b/.  In my script that url is not getting my input variables.

```
        read  "Enter Build date: " a
        read  "Enter build No: " b
        bash /root/script2.sh $a $b
```

Comment: script2.sh is inside script1.sh? How does that work? Your `read` lines aren't written correctly. Are you not getting an error when you try to run this like `script1.sh: line 1: read: `Enter Build date: ': not a valid identifier. I believe if you are going to try to echo your prompt on the same line upon which you do your `read` you need to use read's `-p` flag. `read -p "Enter Build Date: " a`
`?

Comment: i have updated "read -p" still no luck.  script2.sh is inside script1.sh: Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Don't add any other statement with read.**

Try like this,

In script1.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter Build date: "
read a
echo "Enter build no: "
read b
bash /root/script2.sh $a $b
```

In script2.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
a=$1
b=$2
echo "http://download-$a-$b/."
```

NOTE: echo "http://download-$a-$b/." is just for reference to show the value. You can do your desired operation after getting value.